# Google Push notifications response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-pubsub

all!
I'm using Google Push Notifications for Gmail API.
In documents, Google says that server should send a response with status 200, 201, 204 or 102. (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push)
But when I send this response Google continues to spam me with queries with the same history_id.

```
def get_new_messages
    # do something with params
    head :ok
end
```

What should I have besides the status in answer to stop spamming me?
Thanks!

Comment: [mcve] <-- Please show us your code. According to the documentation, and your description of the code, it should work fine.

Comment: @TomLord thanks, added

Comment: Again, according to the documentation, that should work fine. My best guess is that you've actually got an error in the `# do something with params`, so the `200` response is not actually being sent, and instead it's a `500` error or similar?

Comment: Could also be taking too long...["However, a high rate of duplicates may indicate that the client is not acknowledging messages within the configured `ack_deadline_seconds`"](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#duplicates)...looks like that might default to 10 seconds (not 100% sure on this...never used this)